How do you run a for-loop in the Python console for GIMP?
I am trying to run a very simple for-loop:
for obj_name, obj in locals().items():
    if callable(obj):
        print(obj.__name__)

We seem to be able to run a single line of code without any difficulty:
GIMP 2.10.32 Python Console
Python 2.7.18 (default, Oct 27 2021, 07:49:35)  [GCC 11.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)]

>>> print("hello world")
hello world

>>> 2 + 3
5

>>> type(5)
<type 'int'>

However, the loop did not behave the way that I anticipated:
>>> for obj_name, obj in locals().items():
...     if callable(obj):
...         print(obj.__name__)
... 

Nothing printed to the console.

>>> exec("for obj_name, obj in locals().items():\n    if callable(obj):\n     
   print(obj.__name__)")

Again, there the print statement failed to go out to the console.

How do you run a for-loop in the Python console for GIMP?

The for-loop ran just fine, but nothing was printed because there were no callables in the dictionary of local objects.
>>> import itertools as itts
>>> 
>>> it1 = iter(tuple(locals().items()))
>>> 
>>> it2 = iter(tuple(globals().items()))
>>> 
>>> it_merged = itts.chain(it1, it2)
>>> 
>>> for obj_name, obj in it_merged:
...     print(obj_name)
...     if callable(obj):
...         print(obj.__name__)
...

The output is as follows...
USER_DIRECTORY_PUBLIC_SHARE
DODGE_BURN_TYPE_BURN
GRADIENT_BLEND_CIE_LAB
LAYER_MODE_LCH_COLOR
JOIN_MITER
BLEND_CUSTOM
CONVERT_PALETTE_MONO
TRANSPARENT_FILL
LAYER_MODE_BURN_LEGACY
PIXELS
DODGE
CHECK_TYPE_BLACK_ONLY
REPEAT_TRIANGULAR
LAYER_MODE_DIVIDE
PIXEL_FETCHER_EDGE_NONE
PRECISION_U8_LINEAR
FILL_BACKGROUND
LAYER_MODE_SUBTRACT_LEGACY
MIN_RESOLUTION
EXPORT_CAN_HANDLE_ALPHA
USER_DIRECTORY_TEMPLATES
LAYER_COMPOSITE_INTERSECTION
PDB_END
USER_DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
PIXEL_FETCHER_EDGE_SMEAR
COLOR_RENDERING_INTENT_PERCEPTUAL
LAYER_MODE_LINEAR_BURN
CHECK_TYPE_GRAY_CHECKS
PDB_IMAGE
SHADOWS
PDB_ERROR_HANDLER_PLUGIN
COLOR_ERASE_MODE
GRADIENT_SEGMENT_LINEAR
REPEAT_SAWTOOTH
TEXT_DIRECTION_TTB_RTL_UPRIGHT
COLOR_RENDERING_INTENT_RELATIVE_COLORIMETRIC
PDB_STRINGARRAY
DODGE_MODE
SHARPEN_CONVOLVE
PDB_STATUS
PARASITE_UNDOABLE
PDB_STRING
INDEXED
SELECT_CRITERION_COMPOSITE
UNIT_PICA
PDB_INT32
REUSE_PALETTE
PLUGIN
TRANSFORM_BACKWARD
MULTIPLY_MODE
COLOR_TAG_VIOLET
STROKE_PAINT_METHOD
LAYER_MODE_LCH_LIGHTNESS
ADD_MASK_COPY
CUSTOM_PALETTE
HISTOGRAM_BLUE
TRANSFORM_RESIZE_ADJUST
CAP_ROUND
GRADIENT_RADIAL
PARASITE_GRANDPARENT_UNDOABLE
PROGRESS_COMMAND_SET_TEXT


But what are you trying this? Looking for something specific?
